# Why multiply by 0.002 in this line of code: new Date().getTime() * 0.002;

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

Is there any special purpose for multiplying by 0.002 in the following code?

```
var time = new Date().getTime() * 0.002;
```

This code excerpt was taken from [here](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/). I have provided the entire code below also:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function(/* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();
var canvas, context;

init();
animate();

function init() {

canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
canvas.width = 256;
canvas.height = 256;

context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

document.body.appendChild( canvas );

}

function animate() {
    requestAnimFrame( animate );
    draw();
}

function draw() {
    var time = new Date().getTime() * 0.002;
    var x = Math.sin( time ) * 96 + 128;
    var y = Math.cos( time * 0.9 ) * 96 + 128;

    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(245,245,245)';
    context.fillRect( 0, 0, 255, 255 );

    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc( x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true );
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
}
```

Comment: I followed your link and couldn't see that code anywhere. But I'm going to go ahead and say yes, there is a special purpose (just on the basis that multiplying by 0.002 isn't the sort of thing one does by accident).

Comment: Go to the JSFiddle window on the page and click on JavaScript.

Comment: I guess it would get the number of half seconds since january 1 1970. cant find the code in your link.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason JSFiddle doesn't work properly through my worksite's proxy. But in any case can't you provide more context directly in your question?

Answer (score 3):

The code uses `Math.sin( time ) * 96 + 128` as an x-coordinate, and `Math.cos( time * 0.9 ) * 96 + 128` as a y-coordinate. If `time` were a number of milliseconds (as `new Date().getTime()` is), then the x-coordinate and y-coordinate would both vacillate wildly with each successive call, and the dot would not seem to "move", but rather "jump arbitrarily" — sixty times a second, faster than the eye can track it. Multiplying the number of milliseconds by 0.002 causes the x- and y-coordinates of the dot to oscillate in a much smoother fashion, in a way that looks (to the human eye) like motion.

Comment: Right, but dividing by say 500 like so, `new Date().getTime() / 500;` can produce a similar result. Can I assume that 0.002 is arbitrary?

Comment: @Jesse, re: dividing by 500: You're right: in JavaScript, `/ 500` is equivalent to `* 0.002`. I have some thoughts on he might have chosen to write `* 0.002`, but I can't give you a sure answer -- and it doesn't make a difference anyway. Re: arbitrary: I would guess that he tried a few different values until he got a speed that looked good to him. There's definitely nothing magical about `0.002` as opposed to, say, `0.001` or `0.004`.

Comment: @ruakh - `in JavaScript, / 500 is equivalent to * 0.002` - not just in javascript, in mathematics in general. :-) In simple terms, it is a scale factor to control the speed of the animation.

Comment: @RobG: I specified "in JavaScript" because there are a number of related languages, such as C, C++, and Java, where the equivalent of `new Date().getTime() / 500` would perform "integer division". For example, the C expression `25 / 4` evaluates to `6`, not to `6.25`; for the latter, you'd have to write something like `25.0 / 4` or `25 * 0.25`. Sadly, few programming languages hew very closely to "mathematics in general". :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
var time = new Date().getTime() * 0.002;
var x = Math.sin( time ) * 96 + 128;
var y = Math.cos( time * 0.9 ) * 96 + 128;
```

The value returned by the getTime method is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970. That value is used to calculate the next x and y co-ordinates for the circle.

Answer (score 0):

The value controls the location where the circle is drawn as a fraction of the current time.  The smaller the number the slower the animation appears (and more crisp) - the inverse is true for larger numbers.

You can play with the number by clicking the plus icon in the top right corner of the jsFiddle widget - this will take you to the jsFiddle site where you can edit and run the javascript.

Note - It looks like the script in question is not compatible with IE 9 - works fine for me in FF but haven't tested any other browsers...